# Negative curvature towards a certain direction

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

If $u^T\nabla^2 f(z)u$ is strictly negative, can we say that the Hessian $\nabla^2 f(z)$ has at least one negative eigenvalue corresponding to $u$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What do you know about $f$?